# global variables not output correctly

Tags: c, global-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>

float aver(float*,int);
float max = 0, min = 0;      // define global variables

int main() 
{
    int i;
    float num[10];  //input  number
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    printf("%.2f   %.2f   %.2f   ", max, min, aver(num, i)); //output max ,min and aver
    return 0;
}

float aver(float*num,int n)
{
    max = min = num[0];
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        if (max < num[i])
            max = num[i];        //find max
        else if (min > num[i])
            min = num[i];      //find min
        sum += num[i];
    }
    printf("%.2f   %.2f  \n ",max,min);   //output the max and the min in the array num
    return sum/n;
}
```

---

Is is what i input and get.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
9.00   1.00  
0.00   0.00   4.50   Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Why the `max` and the `min` in the function `aver` can output correctly, but in the `main` function they are `0`?

Comment: Why `for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)`? it should be `for (i=0; i<n; i++)`.

Comment: Just dont use global variables, pass the `max` and `min` addresses to `aver` and evaluate that before the `printf` since as **CoolGuy** answered, the order of evaluation for `printf` parameters is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

Order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. So your code may work as expected on some compilers while may give unexpected results on other compilers.

You should replace

```
printf("%.2f   %.2f   %.2f   ",max,min,aver(num, i)); //output max ,min and aver
```

with

```
{
  float average = aver(num, i);
  printf("%.2f   %.2f   %.2f   ",max,min, average); //output max ,min and aver
}
```

to make the code behavior well defined.

---

from C99 §6.5.2.2p10:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of the arguments of `printf` is unspecified,i.e,`max` and `min` can be printed after or before evaluating `aver` function. In your case,`aver` is called  after printing `max` and `min` and then, this function modifies the `max` and `min` variables.

To fix it, just call `aver` as an argument in another `printf`